# jQuery.jgrid.parseDate date formatting

Tags: javascript, date, jqgrid, formatting

I have searched for this but couldn't find anyone trying to do what i am doing with jqGrid formatters.

I have a date which I am trying to parse which is **not** in a jqGrid table, but I am using jqGrid on the site elsewhere and am hoping to parse this date using jqGrid's date parser instead of having to write a seperate method.

I have been messing around with the jGrid object but I need a little help with this.

My date format is `ISO8601Long` i.e. `2013-11-17T09:00:00`

First, I am ensuring the date formats in the formatter are the ones i wish to use:

```
jQuery.jgrid.formatter.date.srcformat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
jQuery.jgrid.formatter.date.newformat = 'j/m/Y g.ia';
```

Next, I call the `jQuery.jgrid.parseDate` method in an attempt to parse the date.

```
jQuery.jgrid.parseDate(0, 0, '2013-11-17T09:00:00');
```

I am not sure what the first two arguments are, but they look like they might accept a srcformat and newformat. Either way, they don't format as I would expect. There is a fourth too, but this seems to only accept an object.

This leaves me with `2013-11-17GMT09:00:00`. While this is a bit easier to understand, it is not in the format I would be expecting. I presume I have missed a step or somehow need to call the formatter after this.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks,

Dale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage of `parseDate` would be the following:

```
var parsedData = $.jgrid.parseDate("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2013-11-17T09:00:00", "j/m/Y g.ia");
```

or

```
var parsedData = $.jgrid.parseDate("ISO8601Long", "2013-11-17T09:00:00", "j/m/Y g.ia");
```

You can use alternatively [Globalize jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).

Comment: Thanks Oleg - I was close but not close enough it seems! Hopefully others will find this useful in the future.